# Как из множества различных значений в одном диапазоне корректно отразить круговую диаграмму?

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть значения температуры за месяц (в каждый день по 4 измерения), мне необходимо создать по ним ***именно*** круговую диаграмму (на matplotlib) через plt.pie(). Значения температуры содержатся в дата-фрейме и находятся все в диапазоне 0-20 градусов. Мне необходимо, чтобы по сегментам диаграммы было расположено кол-во измерений (в качестве об. значения соотношений), результатом которых стала определённая температура (в качестве необ. labels=).

Пока у меня получилось такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял проблему, у вас диаграмма получалась перенасыщенной, поскольку у вас замеры не группируются, а отображаются все. Для придания диаграмме более-менее стройного вида нужно нарезать все множество замеров на дискретные диапазоны с каким-нибудь шагом, например, 1 градус.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp_range = 0, 20  # температурный диапазон для моделирования
# моделируем 31*4 измерений в температурном диапазоне
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(31 * 4) * (temp_range[1] - temp_range[0]) + temp_range[0], columns=['temp'])
# нарезаем все температуры на дискретные диапазоны с шагом в 1 градус. Иначе диапазонов будет столько же, сколько замеров
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df.temp, bins=temp_range[1] - temp_range[0],
                    labels=[f'{i} гр.' for i in range(temp_range[0], temp_range[1])])
cnt = df.bins.value_counts()  # считаем кол-во "температур"
plt.pie(cnt, labels=cnt.index)  # формируем диаграмму
plt.show()  # отображаем
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы меня поняли немного неправильно. У меня уже есть датафрейм и со столбцом с температурой из уже существующего датафрейма (с таким количеством строк, сколько и было измерений) мне и надо работать. В итоге способ решения оказался гораздо проще: создать новый Series из уникальных значений столбца с температурами через .value_counts(), потом в labels= взять .index Series'а, а в значения взять сам Series. Теперь разобраться бы с названиями, потому что на самом-то деле у меня отн. влажность и там до 100 сегментов... Всё в кашу сливается...

Comment: Без ваших данных понять действительно сложно, особенно когда написано - температура, а на самом деле - влажность :) Вы бы привели пример реальных данных в вопросе и точно бы описали, что именно нужно и в чем именно проблема. Тем не менее, предложенный мной способ решения также подойдет ко влажности - просто поставьте шаг не 1%, а, например, 10% в `pd.cut` - и у вас будет 10 надписей вместо 100, и каши не будет.